# php - count files in subfolder-level only, echo total per folder

Tags: php

Following folder structure:

`/files/<user_id>/<filename>.txt`

Examples:

```
`/files/15/file1.txt`
`/files/15/file2.txt`
`/files/21/file1.txt`
`/files/23/file1.txt`
```

I need to count the total number of files in each subfolder, but only on the subfolder level. Meaning, if there is another folder, like `/files/23/dir/file1.txt`, then this folder and its content should not be counted.

Output:

`<folder_name>: <folder_count> files`

Examples:

```
15: 23 files
21: 2 files
23: 5 files
```

How can one do a recursive count for subdirectories, but ignore directories in the subdirectory?

Thanks

Edit:

My code so far:

```
<?php 
    // integer starts at 0 before counting
    $i = 0;
    $path = '../../../../../../../home/bpn_sftp';

    $dirs = glob($path . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($dirs as $dir){

        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
            {
                $file_count = count( glob($dir.'*.txt') );
                echo $dir." has ".$file_count." files<br>";
                $i++;
            }
        }

    }

    echo "Total count: ".$i." files";

?>
```

Comment: *"How can one do a recursive count for subdirectories, but ignore directories in the subdirectory?"* Then, you don't need recursion if you already know the target structure

Comment: Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: @Cid I still need recursion since I have to check if there are any subfolders, and if yes, exclude them from the count, no? Regular count operation seems to include subfolders in the total count per folder.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to make it work with a recursive folder scan, limiting the file count to the filetype I am looking for.

```
<?php 
    // integer starts at 0 before counting
    $i = 0;
    $path = './test';

    $dirs = glob($path . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($dirs as $dir){

        $file_count = count( glob($dir.'/*.txt') );
        echo $dir." has ".$file_count." files<br>";
        $i++;

    }

    echo "Total count: ".$i." files";

?>
```